# How do I output individual <p> tags using HTML Agility Pack to a rich text box?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, formatting, html-agility-pack

I'm just learning how to use HTML Agility Pack to scrape text off of webpages. I am looking to get the biographies of heros in Overwatch by Blizzard from their site. I'm currently using this to find and write the desired text to a rich text box.

```
var paragraphs = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='hero-bio-backstory pad-sm']");

     foreach(HtmlNode node in paragraphs)
     {
         rchTxtBox.AppendText(node.InnerText);
         rchTxtBox.AppendText("\n");
     }
```

What I am trying to get is the InnerText of each < p > with a return line in between them.

```
<div class="hero-bio-backstory pad-sm"> == $0
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Instead of outputting each paragraph with a return character between them, it is writing all of them into one solid chunk. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't look like you're selecting the paragraph nodes...shouldn't the selector be `//div[@class='hero-bio-backstory pad-sm']/p`?

Comment: Well that was the solution. I guess I just need to look into how to call what I want properly. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: Not a problem. I've added an answer explaining a little more of what you were seeing in case it helps you or the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `//div[@class='hero-bio-backstory pad-sm']` is returning one node - the entire `div`. When you then call `InnerText` on this node, it is returning the text in the entire div, sans markup. Therefore you are seeing the behavior you describe: your loop runs once, appends all the text in one chunk, then adds a single trailing newline.

You need to use an XPath expression which will select all the `p` nodes, i.e. `//div[@class='hero-bio-backstory pad-sm']/p`.